# adding config items in Orchard Module

Tags: orchardcms

I was wondering on how to add configurable items in a Orchard module (analogous to appsettings key-value in a webapp). Could anyone me point to the right source/url in the web ?

Answer (score 1):

Orchard has a rich settings infrastructure. It is not as simple to implement as the appsettings.config, but is a lot more powerful. You can add settings to the site (shown in the main 'settings' section of the dashboard) or for a specific content type, content part, field or even a part when it is attached to a specific content type. You can define custom settings parts so that your settings can be managed by end users through the dashboard.

For an example of both site settings and content type settings you can look at the Orchard.Comments module. There are also some good blog posts on creating your own custom settings in your module:

http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/how-to-add-settings-to-your-content-parts-and-items

http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/using-custom-settings-in-orchard-part-2-content-type-settings

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to achieve this is to create a Record and leverage orchards database migration functionality.  Orchard does the heavy lifting and you end up with a strongly typed object and repository!  I believe the examples on the Orchard site use this technique for the custom Content Types but you can create them without just create your model

```
public class Item {
   public string Key {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then in the migration define your table with a table name equal to your model name

```
 SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("Item",
              table => table
               .Column<string>("Key",column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
               .Column<string>("Value", column => column.NotNull()
                  .WithLength(30)
```

Then you can inject a repository where yu need it

```
public class MyDriver : ContentFieldDriver<MyPart>
{
  public MyDriver(IRepository<Item> itemRepository) {... }
```

Thats it!